# AWS Api Gateway create resource with 2 path params

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to create an api url with 2 params in Api gateway with lambda. I already tried with mapping query params and that is working fine but I want to add params in url. With one params its working fine but with 2 its showing error that `Resource's path part only allow a-zA-Z0-9._-: or a valid greedy path variable and curly braces at the beginning and the end.`

[image]

If i just use `{userid+}` that is working fine but I need to add 2 params

Comment: Why do you need the plus sign for both params?

Comment: @AllanChua so how ill get 2 params. I try without + also.

Comment: Are you trying to design a fat function? (Meaning one lambda that handles multiple routes?)

Answer (score 0):

Having a path-based parameter that contains `+` sign inside is called a greedy path, which means that the downstream integration of the endpoint will handle all request starting with the prefix of the path.

eg. Consider a function with a greedy path defined as `path: /horses/{proxy+}`. This lambda function will handle all request that starts with `/horses` regarless of the depth of the sub-resource and its verb.

Thus having the 2nd greedy path in a single URL is invalid.

Perhaps you may wanna consider using a POST resource to handle a request that will accept a request body instead.

```
path: /users
method: POST
```

You will then have to issue a POST request to it using popular libraries such as `fetch`

```js
const url = 'https://api.example.com/post-endpoint';
const data = {
  username: 'foo-user',
  userID: 1
};

// Making the POST request using fetch
const response = await fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', // Set the content type to JSON
    // Add other headers if needed
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data) // Convert data to JSON string
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use greedy path parameter only at the end of the url.

In your case just rename `{userid+}` to `{userid}`.

You should have `{userid}/{username+}`